# Query in SqlServer for Users Currently logged in

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a tblData where users login. In the table they can be either IN or OUT.
What I want is to display the users that are currently logged in.

[image]

Comment: I think you should just make another table that keeps 'IN' Id's and 'Out' Id's keep the Records in a tbldataRecords table seperatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @a table ([Date] date,[Time] Time(7),[Type] varchar(10),ID int, Location int)

Insert into @a Select '20130101','10:00','IN',280,2
union Select '20130101','11:00','IN',280,2
union Select '20130101','12:00','OUT',280,2
union Select '20130101','12:00','IN',111,2
union Select '20130101','12:00','OUT',1,2
union Select '20130101','13:00','IN',1,2


Select * from @a a2
JOIN
(
Select MAX(Cast([Date] as dateTime)+[Time]) DT,ID
from @a
Group by ID
) b
on b.ID=a2.ID and Cast(a2.[Date] as dateTime)+a2.[Time] = b.DT
Where a2.Type='IN'
```

Comment: Error: The data types date and varchar are incompatible in the add operator.

Comment: if you are storing date and time values in Varchar fields (which should not be done) you will have to Cast them [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(v=sql.80).aspx). But I'd recommend using native datatypes. I on my own would store Date and Time together in one single DateTime flield.

Comment: My DATE is of type date and Time is of type time(7)

Comment: I would too, but the DB Admin has it setup that way.

Comment: Sorry, had an bug, should be fixed [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/17351)

Comment: We are almost there, I get 10 and it shouldnt be there. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/17363

Comment: Your SQLFiddle is different from mine, your `Type='IN'` condition is inside instead of outside and Type has to be omit inside, for just getting the MAX Date per ID, Type='IN' is fitering the joined result of MAX Date per ID

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM tblData E
WHERE E.date = convert(date, getdate())
and convert(time, E.time) <= convert(time, getdate())
and E.type = 'IN'
not exists(
    select 'x' from tblData U
    where U.id = E.id
    and U.type = 'OUT'
    and E.date = U.date
    and U.time > E.time
    and convert(time, U.time) <= convert(time, getdate()))
```

Comment: +1 there is an 'AND' missing before not. Apart from that this probably solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
ID,MAX(convert(datetime,DATE)+' '+TIME)  FROM tblData T1 WHERE [Type] = 'IN' AND   convert(datetime,DATE)+' '+TIME>
    (SELECT max(convert(datetime,DATE)+' '+TIME) FROM tblData T2 WHERE T1.ID=T2.ID AND [TYPE]='OUT')
GROUP BY
ID
UNION
SELECT 
ID,convert(datetime,DATE)+' '+TIME  FROM tblData T1 WHERE [Type] = 'IN' AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT convert(datetime,DATE)+' '+TIME FROM tblData T2 WHERE T1.ID=T2.ID AND [TYPE]='OUT')
```

Comment: Is given me this for line 1, Error: The data types date and varchar are incompatible in the add operator.

Comment: My DATE is of type date and Time is of type time(7)

Comment: Please try again, I apologize for not confirming the data types earlier

Comment: My DB Admin just Added a column QDateTime. how can I go about this.

Comment: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: What is the data type of column QDateTime, also is it an additional column other then the columns Date and Time mentioned in the query?

Comment: QDateTime is of type datetme. Columns are, Date,Time,Type,ID, QId, QDatetime

Comment: is column QDatetime containing the combined value of columns Date and Time? What I mean is if value for Date is '2013-06-17' and Time is '11:06:00' so value for QDateTime is '2013-06-17 11:06:00'?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
ID,MAX(QDateTime)  FROM tblData T1 WHERE [Type] = 'IN' AND  QDateTime>
    (SELECT max(QDateTime) FROM tblData T2 WHERE T1.ID=T2.ID AND [TYPE]='OUT')
GROUP BY
ID
UNION
SELECT 
ID, QDateTime  FROM tblData T1 WHERE [Type] = 'IN' AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT  QDateTime FROM tblData T2 WHERE T1.ID=T2.ID AND [TYPE]='OUT')
```